# Generalization of skewness detection in non-uniform case

Tags: machine-learning, inference, frequency

I am not sure if my title reflects what I am attempting to ask. Let me elaborate my question. I want to classify an observation/feature into one of two categories ($A$ and $B$) based on frequency of occurrence of feature in  each category.  For example, a particular observation occurs $x$ times in category A and $y$ times in category B, and I have same number of sample for each category. If $x/(x+y> c$ for some $c > 0.5$, e.g. $c = 2/3$, then I  associate that feature with category A else, if $y/(x+y) > c$ then I associate it with category $B$, else discard the feature as having no discriminating information. Here I was assuming that I have same number of sample from each category. Now, if I had for example, $a$ sample from $A$ and $b$ sample from $B$ to check for the occurrence of features, how do I detect if my observation is skewed towards a category.

Comment: You appear to be using the term 'skewness' in a manner inconsistent with its usual meaning in statistics. I'd suggest you use another term, or at the very least *very carefully define what you mean when you use it*.

Comment: @Glen_b, please reword the question. I have written what I expect, I am not sure if it is correct to say that way.

Comment: *I don't know what you're trying to convey with the word "skewed" there*. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @Glen_b I know that it is not precise, but what I have explained is a practical situation. I want to use that in some machine learning heuristic algorithms.

Comment: You may do one of a couple of things that come to my mind. You may directly under sample the majority class by randomly removing samples from it until neither category A and B are  skewed. After that, you proceed with your proposed technique. The second idea is based on multiplying your scoring function by a weight parameter to reduce the effect of bias of the class distribution. For example, you may multiply x/(x+y) by 1-(size(A)/size(B)).